# Are there logIn/signIn and logOut/signOut icons in material icon list?

Tags: icons

I checked the icon list available at https://material.io/tools/icons/ and the closest matches I see are

For LogIn or SignIn

- **vpn_key** https://material.io/tools/icons/?search=vpn_key&icon=vpn_key&style=baseline
- **input** https://material.io/tools/icons/?search=input&icon=input&style=baseline
- **exit_to_app** https://material.io/tools/icons/?search=exit&icon=exit_to_app&style=baseline

For LogOut or SignOut

- **power_settings_new** https://material.io/tools/icons/?search=power&icon=power_settings_new&style=baseline

are these universally acceptable icons or can you please suggest if there are any other icons

Answer (score 9):

what about those two?

https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons%20Outlined%3Alogout%3A
https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons%20Outlined%3Alogin%3A

Their ids are simply "login" and "logout".

I can use them like this:

```
<mat-icon aria-hidden="false">login</mat-icon>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're using angular mat-icon you can use the exit_to_app
`<mat-icon>exit_to_app</mat-icon>`

Answer (score 3):

## No there is not any icon

No there is not any icon in google's material-design-icons. Check this [issue](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/286) for updates.

I used [LockOpen](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons%20Outlined%3Alock_open) for Sign In and [ExitToApp](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons%20Outlined%3Aexit_to_app) for Sign Up.

Comment: Thanks.. I guess I will use the same icons

Answer (score 1):

Currenty i am using

Angular CLI: 15.0.4

Node: 18.12.1

Package Manager: npm 9.1.3

@angular/material  15.1.0

```
<button mat-icon-button>
  <mat-icon
    aria-hidden="false"
    aria-label="login icon"
    fontIcon="login"
    [ariaSetSize]="50"
    color="warn"
  ></mat-icon>
</button>

<button mat-icon-button>
  <mat-icon
    aria-hidden="false"
    aria-label="logout icon"
    fontIcon="logout"
    [ariaSetSize]="50"
    color="warn"
  ></mat-icon>
</button>
```

[see the icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akyhu.png)